# conflict with styled component classes + antd classes in a single spa microfront application

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, styled-components, single-spa

I'm in a project with a microfront application using single-spa, styled-components and antd.

The problem is:

- I have a component with styled components
- When I go to another url/application and come back (by clicking in the browser's button), **antd classes has more priority than the styled component classes**. prints to understand:

1. **first time** in the application
   [image]
2. i click in the "google button" and it takes me to **another url/application**. but i click in the **go back button (top-left in the print)**
   [image]
3. when i'm back to the same application as before, antd classes are **"more important"** than styled component classes and nothing works as it should.
   [image]

- If i write all styled components with !important or [&& {} (same as important in styled components)](https://styled-components.com/docs/faqs#how-can-i-override-styles-with-higher-specificity) it works. because my styled component class is more important than antd now. but it's a good practice to code all components with !important. And this problem is in my whole application.
- I tried to add styled components and antd as global dependencies in my app-root

```js
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
        "react": "https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js",
        "react-dom": "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js",
        "react-is": "https://unpkg.com/react-is@17.0.2/umd/react-is.production.min.js",
        "styled-components": "https://unpkg.com/styled-components@5.3.3/dist/styled-components.min.js",
        "antd": "https://unpkg.com/antd@4.16.13/dist/antd.min.js",
        "moment": "https://unpkg.com/moment@2.25.3/min/moment.min.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
```

I don't know if the problem is anything about the bundle, when generating new classes. Do you guys have any idea about what could be happening? It means so much to me! Thanks <3

Comment: Nothing about single-spa changes the nature of how styles are handled on the web. What's happening is that both andt and styled-components create classnames that have the same specificity. And it appears that the antd styles are being added later to the document so they are "winning" over the styled-components classes. I have no idea how to fix this but that's at least what appears to be happening.